# extract values from a variable in c++

Tags: c++, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I am new to c++ and I have to call a function from a library that returns the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix G; This is the template of the function

```
std::array< std::pair< Number, Tensor< 1, dim, Number > >, std::integral_constant< int, dim >::value >   eigenvectors   (const SymmetricTensor< 2, dim, Number > &  T,
const SymmetricTensorEigenvectorMethod  method = SymmetricTensorEigenvectorMethod::ql_implicit_shifts);
```

I declared the the output "eigs" in this way:

```
std::array< std::pair< double, Tensor< 1, dim, double >>, 3> eigs;
```

and i call the function in this way:

```
eigs = eigenvectors(G);
```

my question is: the output "eigs" is a matrix or a vector? because when i try to extract eigs[0][0] i have an error:

```
"no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'std::array<std::pair<double, dealii::Tensor<1, 3> >, 3>::value_type' {aka 'std::pair<double, dealii::Tensor<1, 3> >'} and 'int') cout << eigs[0][0];"
```

Any help would be appreciated,

Lorenzo

Answer (score 1):

`eigs` is a `std::array`, but each element of `eigs` is a `std::pair`.  So what you want is this:

```
cout << eigs[0].second[0];
```

Which will access the first element of the `dealii::Tensor`, which is contained in the `.second` member of the `std::pair` at the first position of the `eigs` variable (and again, `eigs` is a `std::array`).

I'm not familiar with deal.II, but I assume a `dealii::Tensor` can be accessed as though it were an array or a vector (i.e. using `operator[]`).